# Batch script that do a backup

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, path

im a beginner in batch script,and im trying to do a script that ask for a file path,then create a folder(in the current folder)and I want the created folder name to be like "sav-DATE-TIME"(for example,right now the folder would be named: sav-2015-12-07-18-55-00) and then copy the file given by the user filepath in the created folder.So far I did this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P pathh=Enter the path
SET foldname=sav%DATE%%TIME%
mkdir %foldname%
cd %foldname%
xcopy /s/e %pathh% %cd%
pause
```

However when I run this,no matter how I enter the path with " or ' or nothing around the path,it always says that the path is incorrect,and also it create a folder with random number(74,56,21...)as the folder name and I dont understand why it wont work properly,wich mean creating the folder with name as said at the begining of question and also saying the path is always incorrect.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use quotes when the variables are expanded (used). The first set of quotes below is only to ensure that you don't have any trailing white space chars. Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P pathh=Enter the path
SET "foldname=sav-%DATE%-%TIME:~0,8%
SET "foldname=%foldname::=-%
echo foldname=%foldname%
rem mkdir "%foldname%"
rem cd "%foldname%"
rem xcopy /s/e "%pathh%" "%cd%"
pause
```

Remove the rem's when it looks good

Comment: I just tried and this still doesnt work.And I think that SET "foldname=sav%DATE%%TIME%" (like you said) should be SET foldname="sav%DATE%%TIME%".But still it says that the path syntax is not  valid even tho the file path really exist

Comment: My bad.  You can't use %DATE% or %TIME% because they contain the characters / and :. Need to strip those out. What format do you really want? Do you need seconds etc?  Do you need to be concerned about internationalization? (date/time format may by country). Please post the results of ECHO,%DATE%%TIME% for your machine and also what format you would like to see for foldname. When looking for this kind of problem you should remove the @ECHO OFF statement and then you will see the problem.

Comment: I just did ECHO,%DATE%%TIME% and I get 2015-12-0721:30:00,98. I dont need internationalization,just want to folder name(foldname) to be like " sav-2015-12-07-21-30-00".thanks

Comment: I edited my answer. Your date/time format is different than mine so you will have to test yourself. See SET /? for explanation. The first set above will will use only the first 8 chars of %TIME%. The second SET will replace all : with -.

Comment: Thank you!! You solved my problem.Also I had error because I was trying to copy a .txt files,while the /s/e parameters applies for directories;so the script was returning an error.Removed /s/e from xcopy /s/e "%pathh%" "%cd%" and now its works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`set foldname=%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%:%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%,%time:~6,2%` this should give you 2015-12-09-10:56,17

Then `mkdir %foldname%`